# How to make boxes with drop effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make boxes into my `Home` page. How do I to make this?

[image]

**Note that** I'm not trying to repeat the same box, but I'm trying to do with each drop effect and margins.

Comment: What do you mean by drop effect? Elaborate a little bit.

Comment: @LokeshSuthar, I've updated my post's image.

Comment: You might want to read a little bit of css basics while you're out experimenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called `overflow:scroll`

**[Click me](http://jsfiddle.net/CPZ4L/1)**

Basically when you want your div to scroll, you need to specify overflow property. It will allow you to scroll the content inside your parent container.

Fixed "Inbox" is obtained by setting `position:fixed`

```
.outerDiv{
    max-width:400px;
    background-color:#eee;
    max-height:400px;
    overflow-y:scroll; /*THIS allows you to enable vertical scroll bar*/
}
.innerDiv{
    display:block;
    min-height:30px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    padding:5px;
    margin:10px;
}
.fixedDiv{
    background-color:blue;
    position:fixed;
    color:white;
    top:0;
    left:5px;
    width:385px;
    height:30px;
    padding:10px;
}
```